# Bash capture all numbers in sequence

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, grep

I have simple Ansible play that run `shell:` command on the remote machine, which return something like this

```
ok: [proxmox] => {
    "CONTAINER_INFO": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "pct list | grep -w test",
        "delta": "0:00:00.463029",
        "end": "2017-10-13 22:21:22.428399",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2017-10-13 22:21:21.965370",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "100        stopped                 test                ",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "100        stopped                 test                "
        ]
    }
}
```

The only useful information I need is the number on the `stdout` in this case `100`.

> Is there a way to filter this out like `grep` command that will return `100` only?

So far best I got is this:

```
ok: [proxmox] => {
    "CONTAINER_INFO": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "pct list | grep -w test | grep -Eo [[:digit:]]",
        "delta": "0:00:00.477083",
        "end": "2017-10-13 22:26:03.258617",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2017-10-13 22:26:02.781534",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "1\n0\n0",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "1",
            "0",
            "0"
        ]
    }
}
```

> Pure Bash

```
root@pve:~# pct list | grep -w "test"
100        stopped                 test
root@pve:~# pct list | grep -w "test2"
101        running                 test2
```

List doesn't really help me in this case.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **awk**:

```
$ cat input.txt | awk 'match($0, /"stdout":\s*"([0-9]+)/,a){print a[1]}'
100
```

Using **perl**:

```
$ cat input.txt | perl -n -e '/"stdout":\s+"(\d+)/ && print $1,"\n"'
100
```

Comment: This is a generic bash answer.  While it would work in Ansible, I think filters are a better option.

Comment: OP doesn't mention ansible version. Filters only start working from version 2.2. So, yes, my solution is generic. And no, it's not bash, it works on any shell.

Comment: The output I get is this `100        stopped                 test                ` for example, so when I try to filter this with either of the above methods; I get `syntax error at -e line 1, near \"+) for perl and `syntax error at or near [` for awk. For some reason I can't escape or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: `pct list | grep -w test`. Perl `pct list | grep -w test | perl -n -e '(d+)'`

Comment: @PraveenM show the exact output of your `grep -w test`

Comment: @MarcLambrichs There are some bash outputs added to the question above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156729/discussion-between-marc-lambrichs-and-praveen-m).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Ansible filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#id26).  This would allow you to get the value `100` using a Regex natively within Ansible.

Comment: Unfortunately the filters doesn't help me here as it return ` "101": "101"`, but thanks for the taking the time to answer.